# How to check product meta value before product update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF field for products which contains text like 'expected Jan 2024', and I need to empty it when product is back in stock. The problem is that I can't find the right action or hook for that. Which one sould I use to check stock **before** update and fire my function only when product is back in stock (not every time it's updated)?

No need to do it for variations, only simple products.

Comment: WordPress+WooCommerce ?

Comment: yes, it's in tags